# What does the sender argument do in practice in several NSWindow methods?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I found no documentation on what the `sender` argument does when I call the [`toggleFullScreen`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419527-togglefullscreen), [`makeKeyAndOrderFront`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419208-makekeyandorderfront), or others. The docs just say that `sender` should be *'The object that sent the message.'*

For example, one cannot retrieve the value of `sender` via the notification passed to `windowDidEnterFullScreen` in the window delegate upon calling `toggleFullScreen`.

What does this argument do in practice? Does it actually matter what value I pass to the aforementioned examples? Will these values ever be seen again?

> In practice, sender is kind of hard to use correctly, because you need to carefully ensure consistency between the senders. The recipient has certain expectations about the sender object (its type, or what messages it responds to) which can't be codified in the type system.

How can this value be accessed from the *'recipient'* side?

Comment: No, see [NSWindowDidEnterFullScreenNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdidenterfullscreennotification/) "The notification object is the NSWindow object entered full screen mode. This notification does not contain a userInfo dictionary.".

Comment: The whole `sender` thing is pervasive throughout AppKit. It made more sense back when Objective C had less static typing, and you were just slinging `id` around everywhere. The idea was that delegate callbacks would inform the reception of whose sent the message. The recipient could then send messages back to the sender, such as to communicate some information across. E.g. an IBAction tells you which button fired it, so you could have one IBAction method as the action on multiple related buttons. Internally you could discriminate the events apart by the sender.

Comment: In practice, `sender` is kind of hard to use correctly, because you need to carefully ensure consistency between the senders. The recipient has certain expectations about the sender object (its type, or what messages it responds to) which can't be codified in the type system. So it's up to you to ensure that for a given class/message pair, every sender is consistent across your whole app. This is pretty hard to do, so I would just largely ignore the entire mechanism, and use other means of communicating information across messages

Comment: @Alexander I kind of get the gist of it, I guess it is similar to the `void *userdata` arguments you see in many callbacks (for example in the GTK library). But what does this look like for `sender`?

Comment: @user16217248 Exactly that, yes. Except instead of C's "any" type (`void *`), it's Objective-C's "any" type (`id`, imported into Swift as `AnyObject`). "But what does this look like for `sender`?" What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Alexander Where would the value be accessed after being passed? In GTK, it would be accessed as the `void *userdata` parameter to the callback function I pass to `g_signal_connect` or similar. Where would the value of `sender` be accessed after calling `window.toggleFullScreen(someValue)`? I could not find any documentation or examples of its usage. The reason I originally asked this question over a year ago was because I wanted to know exactly what would happen differently if I passed `nil` versus if I passed some other non-nil value.

Comment: @user16217248 It depends on a case-by-case basis, but for the specific case of `NSWindow.toggleFullScreen`, I suspect the send gets packaged up into the `Notification` object passed to its [`NSWindowDelegate.windowWillEnterFullScreen`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate/1419563-windowwillenterfullscreen) delegate method (which is a kind of callback)

Comment: @Alexander So [Willeke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70007836/what-does-the-sender-argument-do-in-practice-in-several-nswindow-methods?noredirect=1#comment123754291_70007836) said it could not be accessed in `NSWindowDidEnterFullScreenNotification`, but it could be accessed in `NSWindowDelegate.windowWillEnterFullScreen`? So the `Will` has the userdata but not the `Did`?

Comment: @user16217248 Oh interesting. IDK, it was a guess. The usual pattern is to have some kind of way for a callback or delegate method to be able to check what triggered the event it responds to. If the fullscreen APIs don't have that, then it's kinda questionable why they have the `sender` param on the caller-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those APIs which have a `sender` parameter are part of the Responder Chain.

That means you can connect any UI element for example a button or a menu item – or even multiple in multiple classes – in Interface Builder to the method `makeKeyAndOrderFront` in the First Responder class (the red cube).

And as the name implies the ***first*** class which ***responds*** to the method takes it. The purpose of the `sender` parameter is to determine *who* called the method.

Side note: You can even change the type of the `sender` parameter to a static type (e.g. `NSButton` or `NSMenuItem`) to avoid a type cast if there is only a single connection in Interface Builder.

Comment: What happens if I pass `nil`?

Comment: Nothing, use `nil` if the method is called in code and/or the sender is irrelevant.

Comment: Just to clarify, how do I know if the sender is irrelevant?

Comment: As I said either if the method is called in code or the method is implemented once and you know the sender or it doesn't matter who called the method.

Comment: *'If the method is called in code'* ... So the answer to the question of what does the argument do when I call the method really is *'nothing.'*

Comment: Bottom line: Yes 